# Magento2 Tax/VAT field not showing properly in customer registration based on admin configuration

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, customer-session, eav-attributes, meta

I have Two Website in my magento2.2 **webA** & **webB**

I want "Tax/VAT number" field in different scenarios on my website

> **webA** enabled and required
>
> **webB** enabled and optional

I did the configuration on Store >> Configuration >> Customer Configuration >> Show Tax/VAT Number

> **webA** >> required
>
> **webB** >> optional

When in look to the front-end of my store under create customer I see both the stores have Required and when I do cache refresh it goes optional.

I don't know why this happen, Everything seems to have malfunction.

**Scenarios 1**

> Admin Input
>
> > **webA** >> required
> >
> > **webB** >> optional
>
> Store output
>
> > **webA** >> required
> >
> > **webB** >> required
>
> After flush cache Store output
>
> > **webA** >> optional
> >
> > **webB** >> optional

**Scenarios 2**

> Admin Input
>
> > **webA** >> required
> >
> > **webB** >> required
>
> Store output
>
> > **webA** >> required
> >
> > **webB** >> required
>
> After flush cache Store output
>
> > **webA** >> required
> >
> > **webB** >> required

**Scenarios 3**

> Admin Input
>
> > **webA** >> optional
> >
> > **webB** >> required
>
> Store output
>
> > **webA** >> optional
> >
> > **webB** >> optional
>
> After flush cache Store output
>
> > **webA** >> optional
> >
> > **webB** >> optional

Please help me on this.

Comment: I tried with fresh Magento 2.2 facing the same issue

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10978